# Run method if test doesnt finish

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

Hi Im having an issue i cant figure out, Im running a test on a betting game and at the start of each test I need to create a new game for the database, i run my tests on this game and then delete it, so the database doesnt get full of new games as i run about 20 tests that require this. However, the issue im finding is that if there is some UI change all of these tests might fail and im stuck with 20 games in the data base as the 
game.deletegame() hasnt ran and deleted the game. Is there a way i can get this to run if the test doesnt complete?

Here is my code:

```
public class register_from_pick_screen extends ConditionsWebDriverFactory{

    public static final int TEST_CASE_PASSED_STATUS = 1;
    public static final int TEST_CASE_FAILED_STATUS = 5;


    @Test
    public void register_from_pick()throws Exception{
        CreateGameSD game = new CreateGameSD();
        game.create_Public_Free_to_Play_game_named_with_description(TestGames.test_web_game,TestGames.test_web_game_description);

        GameLobby lobby = new GameLobby();
        lobby.clickElementWithName(TestGames.test_web_game);
        LeaderBoard leaderboard = new LeaderBoard();
        GameId gameid = new GameId();
        gameid.game_id();
        leaderboard.joinGame();
        FixturesScreen fixtures = new FixturesScreen();
        fixtures.four_picks_make();
        fixtures.picks_match_total();
        fixtures.pick_removal_test();
        fixtures.submit_picks();
        Login login = new Login();
        login.select_register_from_login();
        Register register = new Register();
        register.register_in_pick_screen();
        fixtures.submit_picks();
        PickReceipt pick = new PickReceipt();
        pick.your_in_the_game();
        register_from_login_form.addResultForTestCase("16788",TEST_CASE_PASSED_STATUS," ");

        register_from_login_form.addResultForTestCase("17143",TEST_CASE_PASSED_STATUS," ");
        game.delete_game();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BeforeEach -> this annotation on a method will run it before each test. Similar, there is an AfterEach annotation

Comment: So after each should be placed after each test with the method in it and that should run even if it fails??

Comment: Although wouldnt this run the method after every test? Then id be deleting games every time, i only want if to run if the test doesnt complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to delete the games if they do successfully run, but if you would like the games to be deleted if they fail you could try this:

Create a new boolean variable that is set to true if your game runs and stays false if it does not.

```
boolean runSuccess = false;

//game code runs here
//at end of game code add line: runSuccess = true;

//if game code fails to run completely
//runSuccess stays false

if (runSuccess = false)
    game.delete_game();
```

If you wanted to make the game delete it-self no matter what, just add the game.delete_game() method to the beginning of the code before you open any other games so that it loops into the game.delete_game() no matter what. Add the method in your `pick` looping menu so it runs every time a game runs.

Comment: Would the if (runSuccess = false)
    game.delete_game();  still run even if the code isnt reached or will i place these somewhere outside the test??

Comment: @fearghalOreilly you can put that in a method annotated with AfterEach. the method will run after each test, but the delete will (because of your conditional statement) only be executed if runSuccess == false returns true

Comment: Cool, i actually need the game to delete if it passes or fails, maybe that would be easier to do?? The issue im coming up to is that i need an Id from the method to delete the game

Comment: if that is the case, you should run the delete method no matter what (put after methods call) AND use this boolean-controlled if statement so that it runs just in case the game fails to run.